# Symfony 4.4 Multiple firewalls security for multiple providers

Tags: security, symfony4

I have two firewalls, for users and soumissionaire. I created two different providers linking two different entities. I can log in as a user, but never as soumissionaire, i got 302 http error.

I do not understand what I need to add more

security:
encoders:
App\Entity\User:
algorithm: bcrypt

```
    App\Entity\Compte:
        algorithm: bcrypt
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    
    chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [user_provider, soumissionnaire_provider]

    in_memory: { memory: ~ }
    user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: username
    
    soumissionnaire_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\Compte
            property: username
role_hierarchy:
    # Un admin hérite des droits d'utilisateur et de souscommission
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_SOUSCOMMISSION
    # On garde ce rôle superadmin, il nous resservira par la suite
    #ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    soumission:
        pattern: ^/compte
        anonymous: true
        provider:
            soumissionnaire_provider
        form_login:
            login_path: authentificatin_security
            check_path: authentificatin_security
            default_target_path: home
        logout:
            path: deconnexion_security
            target: authentificatin_security
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: true
        provider:
            user_provider
        form_login:
            login_path: security_login
            check_path: security_login
            default_target_path: accueil
        logout:
            path: security_logout
            target: security_login

        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # http_basic: true
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

        # form_login: true
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/analyse, roles: ROLE_SOUSCOMMISSION }
    - { path: ^/compte, roles: ROLE_SOUSMISSIONAIRE }

access_denied_url: /login
```